# Identifying/debugging slowness and sent message duplication in Thunderbird email client

Tags: thunderbird, imap

Are there any tools to pinpoint performance or config issues when sending IMAP messages with Thunderbird client?

Using Thunderbird with IMAP account. It is quite slow to send an email, the message 'Status.. Copying message to Sent Folder' stays for a long time. It can be stopped by browsing to the Sent Folder. But then there are always two copies of the message in that folder.

I have tried my ISP help desk several times with no luck. I followed some of the suggestions at Mozilla KB such as compacting folders, Expunge Inbox on Exit, only using 1 server connection to cache, but problem is still there and I realize it is very hard to solve. Also saw notes on about my ISP (Telstra) indicating current problems with IMAP migration project.

Comment: Unfortunately, software recommendations are not on topic, so its difficult to answer this question without doing so.  I am not sure how using only 1 server connection would improve the speed of the cache, normally you get more throughput, by using multiple connections since you can process data across those connections at the sametime.

Comment: It might help if you add your own email address as automatic bcc for all your outgoing emails (in Account Settings / Copies & Folders), and in the same place uncheck 'Place a copy in'. Your ISP should send your outgoing emails back (to your Inbox) and they will be there instead of Sent Items (and IMO it is a better place for them, easier to follow a thread). It will prevent any delay while T'bird tries to copy your outgoing email to your Sent Items.

Comment: Thanks gogoud, I set that up and it is much quicker now. It makes more sense as you suggest. I'm happy to accept this an the answer if you like.

Still not sure why Thunderbird takes so long to copy emails to 'Sent Items'. When I use a different mail client on my tablet, it is much quicker to do this.

Comment: BCC  to ny email is working well and helps to build threads. But I still can't turn off the "Place a copy in' option. I unticked it. It is grayed out but still defaulting to the 'Sent Items' folder.